# Can I use a custom function to pull data from a csv file?

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I need to extract data from a csv file into an existing excel file. I have little knowledge of custom functions and the deeper mechanics of excel as a whole so with the help of GPT 3.5 I developed a custom function to extract data from a test csv file with 2 records.

Here is the function GPT gave me:

```
Function GetCSVCellValueFromRecord(csvFilePath As String, recordIndex As Long, targetColumnName As String) As Variant
    Dim csvContent As String
    Dim lines() As String
    Dim headers() As String
    Dim columnIndex As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Read the entire CSV file into a string
    Open csvFilePath For Input As #1
    csvContent = Input$(LOF(1), 1)
    Close #1
    
    ' Split the CSV content into lines
    lines = Split(csvContent, vbCrLf)
    
    ' Get the headers from the first line
    headers = Split(lines(0), ",")
    
    ' Find the column index of the target data
    columnIndex = -1
    For i = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
        If Trim(headers(i)) = targetColumnName Then
            columnIndex = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Return an error if the column name is not found
    If columnIndex = -1 Then
        GetCSVCellValueFromRecord = CVErr(xlErrValue)
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' Check if the requested record index is within bounds
    If recordIndex >= 1 And recordIndex <= UBound(lines) Then
        Dim fields() As String
        fields = Split(lines(recordIndex), ",")
        If UBound(fields) >= columnIndex Then
            GetCSVCellValueFromRecord = Trim(fields(columnIndex))
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
    
    ' Return an error if the record or data is not found
    GetCSVCellValueFromRecord = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

The function calls I tried are :=GetCSVCellValueFromRecord("potter.csv",1,"time")  (the csv is in the same folder as the worksheet)
=GetCSVCellValueFromRecord(Potter.csv,2,comment)
both returned a #Value! error. I'm unsure what went wrong or where to go from here

My ultimate goal is to be able to type the csv file name into a field and have function calls refer to that cell in order to update all relevant fields with information from the csv.

Comment: To debug this, you should call it from a `Sub`routine, perhaps stepping through with F8, or judiciously using `Debug.Print`, `Debug.Assert`, watches, breakpoints, etc.

Comment: Btw `CVErr(xlErrrValue)` is the `#Value!` error, which your function is already set to return in some instances.

Comment: Try passing in the full path to the CSV file.

Comment: Does your CSV file begin with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)?

Comment: The header matching test is case sensitive - you could alter the code to ignore case.

Comment: If you open the CSV file in notepad for instance, are the headers wrapped in double-quotes? That would block a match also.

Comment: Whether it works or not just passing the file path would depend on what is the "current directory" (`curdir()`)when the UDF runs.  If it's not the same as where the CSV is saved then it would error out.

Comment: Please, try `GetCSVCellValueFromRecord(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\potter.csv",1,"time")`. Supposing that the active document is the one existing in the same path with the csv file to be processed....

Comment: @FaneDuru - I think this is intended as a UDF to be called from a worksheet.

Comment: @Tim Williams Yes, you are right...

Comment: @Tim Williams passing in the full file path does work , however I was hoping for a way in which I wouldn't need to. I can confirm both the active document and csv are in the same directory

Comment: @FaneDuru GetCSVCellValueFromRecord(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\potter.csv",1,"time")  returns the same #Value! error

Comment: If you only want to pass in the file name then you can use `Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & csvFilePath For Input As #1`

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the suggestions. The issue has changed someone so I've edited the post to reflect that.

Comment: Ideally you could share a sample CSV which we can use to reproduce the problem(s) you describe.  Otherwise there's no way for us to know we're testing under the same conditions you're using.  Might be useful instead of returning a generic error your UDF instead returned something like `?column?` if the header was not matched, or `?record?` if there was no matching record.

Comment: Also please use one post for one question - if you just make rolling updates then the gist of the question is lost.

Comment: `lines(UBound(lines) - recordIndex)` why not `lines(recordIndex)` ?  `lines(0)` is the headers, `lines(1)` is the first record, `lines(2)` the second, etc etc.

Comment: I see you're back to `fields = Split(lines(recordIndex), ",")` - is it now working?

Comment: @TimWilliams I've rolled back this post and made a new post @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76965002/pulling-data-from-csv-files-larger-than-5-records  . As for the lines(UBound(lines) - recordIndex) . The csv file has the most recent record as the first line and for my purposes I need the oldest record to be treated as the first, this was my work around (i'm really just stumbling around trying to make this work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue is you need the full path but only want to pass in the filename, then this change

```vb
Function GetCSVCellValueFromRecord(csvFilePath As String, recordIndex As Long, _
                                  targetColumnName As String) As Variant
    Dim csvContent As String
    Dim lines() As String, headers() As String
    Dim columnIndex As Long, i As Long, ff As Integer
    
    ' Read the entire CSV file into a string
    ff = FreeFile 'don't use a hard-coded value...
    Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & csvFilePath For Input As ff
    csvContent = Input$(LOF(ff), ff)
    Close ff
    '...etc
```

...should do what you want as long as all CSV files are in the same folder where the workbook with the UDF is saved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function to answer the OP's question directly and specifically.

This has been tested on a very simple CSV file as follows -

| ShipperID | CompanyName | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Speedy Express | (503) 555-9831 |
| 2 | United Package | (503) 555-3199 |
| 3 | Federal Shipping | (503) 555-9931 |

```
Option Explicit

Sub sbTest()
' MsgBox NotIn("abcdef", "ab")
' MsgBox IsIn("abcdef", "ab")
' MsgBox fnGetValueCSV("s.csv", 2, "CompanyName")
' MsgBox fnGetValueCSV("s.csv", -2, "CompanyName")
 MsgBox fnGetValueCSV("zz.csv", 20, "MaxCellVoltage")
End Sub

Public Function fnGetValueCSV(sCSVFileName As String, recordIndex As Long, targetColumnName As String) As Variant ' As String
' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76947796/can-i-use-a-custom-function-to-pull-data-from-a-csv-file
' this is the spec  -  (csvFilePath As String, recordIndex As Long, targetColumnName As String) as Variant
' taskkill /F /IM excel.exe - kill excel.exe from the CMD line when it is in an infinite loop
' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function
' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/cverr-function
' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/cell-error-values

    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim iTxtFile As Integer
    Dim strFileText As String
    Dim zz As Long
    Dim iHdrPos As Long
    Dim iNumOfCommas As Long ' the number of commas to find up to the targetColumnName
    Dim sComma As String
    Dim iCommaPos As Long
    Dim iCommaPos2 As Long
    Dim arrLines() As String
    sComma = ","
    
    On Error GoTo Label_CSV_File_Name_Error
    strFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & sCSVFileName ' CSV is in the same place as the Excel workbook.
    iTxtFile = FreeFile
    Open strFileName For Input As FreeFile
    strFileText = Input(LOF(iTxtFile), iTxtFile)
    Close iTxtFile
    On Error GoTo Label_Unknown_Error
    
    arrLines = Split(strFileText, vbCrLf) ' assumes the CSV file is perfectly formed with vbCrLf at the end of each line and nowhere else
    
    If recordIndex < 1 Then
        ' line 0 is the header line, line 1 is the first data line
        fnGetValueCSV = CVErr(2015) ' #VALUE!
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    If NotIn(arrLines(0), targetColumnName) Then
        ' return #VALUE! targetColumnName not found in header line
        fnGetValueCSV = CVErr(2015)  ' #VALUE!
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    iHdrPos = InStr(1, arrLines(0), targetColumnName) ' find the character position of the targetColumnName
    iNumOfCommas = iHdrPos - Len(Replace(Mid(arrLines(0), 1, iHdrPos), sComma, "")) ' the number of commas up to the target column name
    iCommaPos = 1
    For zz = 1 To iNumOfCommas Step 1 ' find the character position of the comma in the data line at recordindex
        iCommaPos = InStr(iCommaPos + 1, arrLines(recordIndex), sComma)
    Next zz
    iCommaPos2 = InStr(iCommaPos + 1, arrLines(recordIndex), sComma) ' the character position of the comma after the data we want
    fnGetValueCSV = Mid(arrLines(recordIndex), iCommaPos + 1, iCommaPos2 - iCommaPos - 1) ' finally return the value in the data line
    Exit Function
    
Label_CSV_File_Name_Error:
    ' return #NAME? file not found
    fnGetValueCSV = CVErr(2029) ' | xlErrName | 2029 | #NAME? |
    Exit Function

Label_Unknown_Error:
    fnGetValueCSV = "#ERROR!" & "**" & Err.Number & "**" & Err.Description
    Exit Function

End Function

Function NotIn(sText As String, sFind As String) As Boolean
    If InStr(1, sText, sFind) = 0 Then
       NotIn = True
    Else
       NotIn = False
    End If
End Function
```

The helper function NotIn wraps the `INSTR()` function making it easier to understand the code, particularly which way round the parameters are
for the text to search and the text to find.

The routine will not work if the CSV file has CRLF anywhere other than the end of a line. Clearly it will also not cope with commas embedded in the text values of the data.

Here is an example of a valid CSV file produced by Excel. It has text enclosed by double quotes where there is a CRLF within the text field, for example the address beginning "507...
It also has escaped double quotes where they occur within a text field. For example ""The Art of the Cold Call""
Text fields with commas within them would also be enclosed in double quotes.

1,Davolio,Nancy,Sales Representative,Ms.,08/12/1948,01/05/1992,"507 - 20th Ave. E.
Apt. 2A",Seattle,WA,98122,USA,(206) 555-9857,5467,,"Education includes a BA in psychology from Colorado State University in 1970.  She also completed ""The Art of the Cold Call.""  Nancy is a member of Toastmasters International.",2