# Pulling data from csv files larger than 5 records

Tags: excel, vba, function, csv

For more context see my first post: [First Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76947796/can-i-use-a-custom-function-to-pull-data-from-a-csv-file?noredirect=1#comment135678552_76947796)

I need to extract data from a csv file into an existing excel file. I have little knowledge of custom functions and the deeper mechanics of excel as a whole so with the help of GPT 3.5 I developed a custom function to extract data from a test csv file with 2 records.

Here is the function GPT gave me with a few adjustments based on the feedback I've been given:

```
Function GetCSVCellValueFromRecord(csvFilePath As String, recordIndex As Long, targetColumnName As String) As Variant
    Dim csvContent As String
    Dim lines() As String
    Dim headers() As String
    Dim columnIndex As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Read the entire CSV file into a string
    Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & csvFilePath For Input As #1
    csvContent = Input$(LOF(1), 1)
    Close #1
    
    ' Split the CSV content into lines
    lines = Split(csvContent, vbCrLf)
    
    ' Get the headers from the first line
    headers = Split(lines(0), ",")
    
    ' Find the column index of the target data
    columnIndex = -1
    For i = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
        If Trim(headers(i)) = targetColumnName Then
            columnIndex = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Return an error if the column name is not found
    If columnIndex = -1 Then
        GetCSVCellValueFromRecord = CVErr(xlErrValue)
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' Check if the requested record index is within bounds
    If recordIndex >= 1 And recordIndex <= UBound(lines) Then
        Dim fields() As String
        fields = Split(lines(UBound(lines) - recordIndex), ",")  ' Remove the subtraction of 1 here
        If UBound(fields) >= columnIndex Then
            GetCSVCellValueFromRecord = Trim(fields(columnIndex))
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    
    ' Return "N/A" if the record or data is not found
    GetCSVCellValueFromRecord = "N/A"
End Function
```

I have a cell containing the name of the desired csv file  and my function calls refer to this cell in order to update all relevant fields with information from the csv.

Function call example: `=GetCSVCellValueFromRecord(F1, 1, "Comment")` If a record cannot be found "N/A" is returned.

The function works well with a small csv file of 5 records except where for the nonexistent 6th record, where it returned the names of the specified columns, then went on to correctly display "N/A" for the nonexistent 7th to 20th record. I'm unsure what caused this error. When testing a file with 10 records , the function fails outright and returns incorrect data for all field and N/A for fields that should be present.

Once again I'm unsure on the issue. Please advise

The csv file has the most recent record as the first line and for my purposes I need the oldest record to be treated as the first

Data from Working csv:

```txt
Date,Time,Service provider,Client name,Client phone,Comment,Service category
24/8/2023,01:00 PM - 01:55 PM,Tim Robinson,Severus Mitsu,18765894838,"5.Checked only 1 mirror before moving off
",Manual General License
24/8/2023,10:15 AM - 11:10 AM,Tim Robinson,Severus Mitsu,18765894838,"4.Started the vehicle properly
",Manual General License
24/8/2023,09:20 AM - 10:15 AM,Tim Robinson,Severus Mitsu,18765894838,"3.Failed to disengage parking brake
",Manual General License
24/8/2023,08:25 AM - 09:20 AM,Tim Robinson,Severus Mitsu,18765894838,"2.Failed to engage seatbelt
",Manual General License
24/8/2023,07:30 AM - 08:25 AM,Tim Robinson,Severus Mitsu,18765894838,"1.Successfully Opened door
",Manual General License
```

Data from broken csv:

```txt
Date,Tim e,Service,"Service provider","Client name","Client phone",Comment,"Service category"
26-08-2023,"01:00 PM - 01:55 PM","Nissan Frontier #CO 026","Harold  Richards","Severus Mitsu",+18765894838,"10. Excessive Speeding","Manual General License"
26-08-2023,"10:15 AM - 11:10 AM","Nissan Frontier #CO 026","Harold  Richards","Severus Mitsu",+18765894838,"9.Ran the red lights","Manual General License"
26-08-2023,"09:20 AM - 10:15 AM","Nissan Frontier #CO 026","Harold  Richards","Severus Mitsu",+18765894838,"8.Mastered Parallel Parking","Manual General License"
26-08-2023,"08:25 AM - 09:20 AM","Nissan Frontier #CO 026","Harold  Richards","Severus Mitsu",+18765894838,"7.botched attempt at parallel parking","Manual General License"
26-08-2023,"07:30 AM - 08:25 AM","Nissan Frontier #CO 026","Harold  Richards","Severus Mitsu",+18765894838,"6. Making good progress","Manual General License"
24-08-2023,"01:00 PM - 01:55 PM","L200 Mitsubishi #794 AL","Tim Robinson","Severus Mitsu",+18765894838,"5.Checked only 1 mirror before moving off
","Manual General License"
24-08-2023,"10:15 AM - 11:10 AM","L200 Mitsubishi #794 AL","Tim Robinson","Severus Mitsu",+18765894838,"4.Started the vehicle properly
","Manual General License"
24-08-2023,"09:20 AM - 10:15 AM","L200 Mitsubishi #794 AL","Tim Robinson","Severus Mitsu",+18765894838,"3.Failed to disengage parking brake
","Manual General License"
24-08-2023,"08:25 AM - 09:20 AM","L200 Mitsubishi #794 AL","Tim Robinson","Severus Mitsu",+18765894838,"2.Failed to engage seatbelt
","Manual General License"
24-08-2023,"07:30 AM - 08:25 AM","L200 Mitsubishi #794 AL","Tim Robinson","Severus Mitsu",+18765894838,"1.Success fully Opened door
","Manual General License"
```

Comment: Worth mentioning (from your previous post) "The csv file has the most recent record as the first line and for my purposes I need the oldest record to be treated as the first"

Comment: I'll add it to the post.  Thanks

Comment: It would be better to open each CSV in Notepad (not Excel) and copy and paste the content from there, so we can be sure of the format.  Excel does things when opening CSV files.

Comment: Alright, I've edited the post

Comment: Some of your quoted field values contain newlines.  Splitting on vbCrLf and comma only works if your file only has those thing between lines and between fields: it doesn't work if field values might contain either of those....

Comment: Do you mean the data from the first 5 records and the working csv?, i'm unsure why the line breaks for those records as both that data and the new 5 records were created in the same way, from the same app and exported in the same manner

Comment: I can't say why they're different, but that does seem to be the problem. You need a better (more complex) CSV parser...

Comment: I will update my answer later to add a function that should read your "problem" files.

Comment: You can just use `Get & Transform => Get Data => from Text/CSV` (aka `Power Query`) to import the data. Works on your sample with no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your quoted field values contain newlines. Splitting on `vbCrLf` and comma only works if your file only has those thing between lines and between fields: it doesn't work if field values might contain either of those.

To make it clearer this will show you where the line breaks are in your file (any of vbCrLf/vbLf/vbCr):

```vb
    ff = FreeFile ' Read the entire CSV file into a string...
    Open ThisWorkBook.path & "\" & csvFilePath For Input As ff
    csvContent = Input$(LOF(ff), ff)
    Close ff
    
    csvContent = Replace(csvContent, vbCrLf, "<CrLf>")
    csvContent = Replace(csvContent, vbCr, "<Cr>")
    csvContent = Replace(csvContent, vbLf, "<Lf>")
    csvContent = Replace(csvContent, "<CrLf>", "<CrLf>" & vbLf)
    Debug.Print csvContent
```

Some records have CrLf *inside the quotes* - these are not line-separating new lines but newlines embedded in the field data.

```txt
Date,Tim e,Service,"Service provider","Client name","Client phone",Comment,"Service category"<CrLf>
26-08-2023,"01:00 PM - 01:55 PM","Nissan Frontier #CO 026","Harold  Richards","Severus Mitsu",+18765894838,"10. Excessive Speeding","Manual General License"<CrLf>
26-08-2023,"10:15 AM - 11:10 AM","Nissan Frontier #CO 026","Harold  Richards","Severus Mitsu",+18765894838,"9.Ran the red lights","Manual General License"<CrLf>
26-08-2023,"09:20 AM - 10:15 AM","Nissan Frontier #CO 026","Harold  Richards","Severus Mitsu",+18765894838,"8.Mastered Parallel Parking","Manual General License"<CrLf>
26-08-2023,"08:25 AM - 09:20 AM","Nissan Frontier #CO 026","Harold  Richards","Severus Mitsu",+18765894838,"7.botched attempt at parallel parking","Manual General License"<CrLf>
26-08-2023,"07:30 AM - 08:25 AM","Nissan Frontier #CO 026","Harold  Richards","Severus Mitsu",+18765894838,"6. Making good progress","Manual General License"<CrLf>
24-08-2023,"01:00 PM - 01:55 PM","L200 Mitsubishi #794 AL","Tim Robinson","Severus Mitsu",+18765894838,"5.Checked only 1 mirror before moving off<CrLf>
","Manual General License"<CrLf>
24-08-2023,"10:15 AM - 11:10 AM","L200 Mitsubishi #794 AL","Tim Robinson","Severus Mitsu",+18765894838,"4.Started the vehicle properly<CrLf>
","Manual General License"<CrLf>
24-08-2023,"09:20 AM - 10:15 AM","L200 Mitsubishi #794 AL","Tim Robinson","Severus Mitsu",+18765894838,"3.Failed to disengage parking brake<CrLf>
","Manual General License"<CrLf>
24-08-2023,"08:25 AM - 09:20 AM","L200 Mitsubishi #794 AL","Tim Robinson","Severus Mitsu",+18765894838,"2.Failed to engage seatbelt<CrLf>
","Manual General License"<CrLf>
24-08-2023,"07:30 AM - 08:25 AM","L200 Mitsubishi #794 AL","Tim Robinson","Severus Mitsu",+18765894838,"1.Success fully Opened door<CrLf>
","Manual General License"<CrLf>
```

EDIT: this successfully reads the content from the "problem" file:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Debug.Print GetCSVCellValueFromRecord("Test2.csv", 1, "Comment")
    '>> 1.Success fully Opened door
    Debug.Print GetCSVCellValueFromRecord("Test2.csv", 2, "Comment")
    '>> 2.Failed to engage seatbelt
    Debug.Print GetCSVCellValueFromRecord("Test2.csv", 1, "Commentx")
    '>> ?header?
    Debug.Print GetCSVCellValueFromRecord("Test2.csv", 4, "Comment")
    '>> 4.Started the vehicle properly
    Debug.Print GetCSVCellValueFromRecord("Test2.csv", 30, "Comment")
    '>> ?rec num?
End Sub


Function GetCSVCellValueFromRecord(csvFilePath As String, recordIndex As Long, targetColumnName As String) As Variant
    Dim numLines As Long, lines As Collection
    Dim headers() As String, fields() As String
    Dim columnIndex As Long, i As Long
   
    Set lines = CSVToLines(ThisWorkBook.path & "\" & csvFilePath)
    numLines = lines.Count
    If numLines = 0 Then
        GetCSVCellValueFromRecord = "?no data?"
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' Find the column index of the target data
    headers = lines(1) ' Get the headers from the first line
    columnIndex = -1
    For i = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
        If Trim(headers(i)) = targetColumnName Then
            columnIndex = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' check the column name was found
    If columnIndex = -1 Then
        GetCSVCellValueFromRecord = "?header?"
    Else
        ' record index is within bounds?
        If recordIndex >= 1 And recordIndex <= lines.Count - 1 Then
            fields = lines(numLines - (recordIndex - 1))
            If UBound(fields) >= columnIndex Then
                GetCSVCellValueFromRecord = Trim(fields(columnIndex))
                Exit Function
            End If
        Else
            GetCSVCellValueFromRecord = "?rec num?"
        End If
    End If
End Function

'Return the content from a CSV file as a Collection of
'  arrays, one array per line
'Account for quoted fields containing commas, quotes, or newlines
Function CSVToLines(csvFilePath As String) As Collection

    Dim csvContent As String, line As String, cNext As String
    Dim c, col As New Collection
    Dim i As Long, ff As Integer, length As Long, inQ As Boolean
    
    ff = FreeFile ' Read the entire CSV file into a string...
    Open csvFilePath For Input As ff
    csvContent = Input$(LOF(ff), ff)
    Close ff
    
    csvContent = Replace(csvContent, vbCrLf, vbLf) & " " 'normalize newlines and add a space
    length = Len(csvContent) - 1                         'skip the added space when looping...
    inQ = False                                          'not yet inside a quoted field
    i = 1
    Do While i < length
        c = Mid(csvContent, i, 1)
        cNext = Mid(csvContent, i + 1, 1)
        If c = """" Then       'already in quotes?
            If cNext = """" Then
                line = line & c     'was a doubled-up quote - add one quote
                i = i + 1           'skip the next character
            Else
                inQ = Not inQ       'switching in/out of a quoted field
            End If
        Else
            If Not inQ Then
                'Not in a quoted field - decide how to handle the character
                Select Case c
                    Case vbLf   'not inside quotes, so this is the end of a line...
                        col.Add Split(line, Chr(0))  'split fields on chr(0)
                        line = ""
                    Case ",": line = line & Chr(0) 'sub comma for chr(0) for later splitting
                    Case Else: line = line & c
                End Select
            Else
                'In a quoted field: add each character unless a vblf
                '  change behaviour to suit your needs....
                Select Case c
                    Case vbLf 'do nothing?
                    Case Else: line = line & c
                End Select
            End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    If Len(line) > 0 Then col.Add Split(line, Chr(0)) 'add any remaining line
    Set CSVToLines = col
End Function
```

Comment: Did the edit fix the problem?

Comment: you my friend are an absolute blessing. This works perfectly. Thanks for all the help !

Comment: Glad it was useful.